# Placing pdf link in codeigniter website

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to place pdf link in CI: http://www.gsa-constructionspecialist.com/articles/article/detail/tugas-lpjk-ke-5

I wonder why I cannot link it. I already place the file address name, yet it comes back to the original file when I click it.

Try another file which I copy exactly from the cpanel: http://www.gsa-constructionspecialist.com/articles/article/detail/visi-dan-misi-training-names-gsa

It has that strange file it carries me to the cpanel which requires a password. That's not a good idea for the visitors.

Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: remove unnecessary space and symbols from your file name. show the html part

Comment: I already remove all unnecessary space and symbol.  Try click this link:  http://www.gsa-constructionspecialist.com/articles/article/detail/tugas-lpjk-ke-5